# Get latest status update for every user in the database

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have `status_updates` table which contains rows with each status update for each user,

```
id      nickname    status  timestamp
-----------------------------------------------
14638   lovely_john offline 2020-07-14 08:37:18
14640   big_papa    online  2020-07-14 08:57:10
```

When status changes, a new row is added.

How do I select the latest single row (in accordance to the timestamp) for each user and get them  in one query? So, if I have 100 users, I will get 100 rows with the latest status change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is best handled by [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```
select distinct on (nickname) *
  from status_updates
 order by nickname, timestamp desc;
```

Comment: Except it should be `distinct on (nickname)`I guess ? Same in the order by

Comment: @Lotram  Good point.  I assumed `id` was the user id rather than the status id.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query. You have to use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
select id, nickname, status, timestamp
from
(select id, nickname, status, timestamp, row_number() over(partition by user_id order 
by timestamp desc) as rnk) qry
where rnk = 1;
```

This will provide you the latest record of each user